# nodejs - Function Return Not Exiting

Tags: node.js, return

I have a function that does a series of tests. If the first test fails the function should exit, however it doesn't:

```
function checkSite(site) {
console.log("Checking if site is already processed or processing");
// Processed Sites
fs.readFile("processed.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {
 if (data.indexOf(site) > -1) {
  console.log("Processed");
  return "Processed";
 } else {
  console.log("Not Processed");
 }
});
fs.readFile("processing.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {
if (data.indexOf(site) > -1) {
 console.log("Processing");
 return "Processing";
} else {
 console.log("Not Processing, Queue for Processing");
 // Queue for Processing
 fs.appendFile(fileProcessing, site, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
 });
}
});
return "Success";
}
```

I'm getting console output of "Processed" followed by "Processing". I should never see "Processing" with the return there. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you seriously code with one space per indent level?

Comment: No, this is how it was formatted when I copied it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`return "Processed"` is just returning from the callback function, not from `checkSite()` so it does not influence what happens next.

`fs.readFile()` is asynchronous.  If you want the second `fs.readFile()` to wait for the first to complete or you want to not execute further actions after the first `fs.readFile()` finishes successfully, you will have to code this differently.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function checkSite(site) {
    console.log("Checking if site is already processed or processing");
    // Processed Sites
    fs.readFile("processed.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {
        if (data.indexOf(site) > -1) {
            console.log("Processed");
        } else {
            console.log("Not Processed");
            fs.readFile("processing.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {
                if (data.indexOf(site) > -1) {
                    console.log("Processing");
                } else {
                    console.log("Not Processing, Queue for Processing");
                    // Queue for Processing
                    fs.appendFile(fileProcessing, site, function(err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note: you can't return the success or failure result directly from `checkSite()` because the `fs.readFile()` operations are asynchronous and thus `checkSite()` returns before those operations are done.  If you want to communicate the result back to the caller of `checkSite()` then, you will either need to pass in a callback function that gets called with the result, use the structure of promises to help you with that or switch to synchronous functions instead of async versions (not usually recommended).

Comment: I was trying to avoid nesting my if/else statements. Apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: Use promises for chaining sequential operations if you want to avoid multiple layers of nesting.

Comment: Can you add an example of using promises in this scenario? I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the concepts.