# Why is my cloud function returning the last return value instead of an earlier one?

Tags: android, typescript, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a button on the client side that is helping me test a simplified version of a backend function. For some reason, the client side (Logcat in Android Studio) is returning `test button isUsernameAvailable: Success. result.data = 2000`. When I look at the Firebase console, I see that the code reached `_isUsernameAvailable REACHED THEN`. However, I don't understand why the client received a `2000` instead of a `5`. If it reached the aforementioned section, the line after that reads `return 5`. Why didn't my client receive a `5`?

Client code:

```
testbutton.setOnClickListener() {
            functions = Firebase.functions

            var data = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
            data["username"] = "ThisUsernameDoesntExist" 

            functions.getHttpsCallable("isUsernameAvailable")
            .call(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener {result ->
                    Log.e(tag, "test button isUsernameAvailable: Success. result.data = " + result.data.toString())

                }
                .addOnFailureListener {exception ->
                    Log.e(tag, "test button failure exception: $exception")
                }
        }
```

Cloud Function code:

```
//Check if username is available (callable from client)
exports.isUsernameAvailable = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  const username = data.username 
  await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  .then(result => {
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable REACHED THEN ')
    return 5
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable REACHED CATCH ')
    return 6
  })
  
  return 2000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735878/7031308) partly explained what's happening on your code. To apply on your case, `return 5` is just returning from the Firestore callback function and it does not cause your main function process to end.

A solution is to create a variable to assign the value whenever an event is met instead of returning it:

```
exports.isUsernameAvailable = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  const username = data.username 
  var returnCode = 0
  await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  .then(result => {
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable REACHED THEN ')
    returnCode = 5
  })
 .catch(error => {
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable REACHED CATCH ')
    returnCode = 6
 })
 
 if (returnCode != 2000){
    return returnCode
 }
 
 return 2000
});
```